# What is the best way to handle Http Exception error messages in vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a vue SPA  project as front-end and Laravel as my back-end. I realized that on every component methods I keep repeating  the same code over and over. I would like more advice on how to make a global class that will handle some of the the `Http Exception error messages` that have been return from the back-end server with or without customized messages Instead of checking it on every method DRY code.

Here is what I have been doing so far:

```
catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 422) {
        this.serverValidation.setMessages(error.response.data.errors);
      } elseif (error.response.status === 403) {
        this.error_403 = error.response.data.errors;
      } elseif(error.response.status === 402) {
        this.error_402 = error.response.data.errors;
      }
      ....
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually make a js/mixins/Errors.js file with all my error methods and then just include the mixin in my vue files.

```
export const errorsMixin = {
methods: {
    errorClass(item, sm = false) {
        return { 'form-control': true, 'form-control-sm': sm, 'is-invalid': this.validationErrors.hasOwnProperty(item) }
    },
    buttonClass() {
        return ['btn', 'btn-primary', this.saving ? 'disabled' : '']
    },
    handleError(error) {
        this.saving = false
        if (error.response.status == 422) {
            this.validationErrors = error.response.data.errors;
        } else {
            alert(error.response.data.message)
        }
    },
}
}
```

In each vue file:

```
import { errorsMixin } from '../../mixins/Errors.js'
export default {
    mixins: [errorsMixin],

    ......
    .catch((err) => {
        this.handleError(err)
    })

}
```

Comment: I made some few changes to fit my needs, but your suggestion works like a champ. Thanks